# How to add a constant value to every element of a Numpy array but the diagonal elements?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to finish defining the function below.

```
def add_val_to_non_diag(A, val):
    pass
```

Here is what I want to happen:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]

add_val_to_non_diag(A, 1)
```

Output

```
[[1, 3, 4],
 [5, 5, 7],
 [8, 9, 9]]
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the value to each element, and subtract back from the diagonal.

```
import numpy as np

def add_val_to_non_diag(A, v):
    return A + v * (1 - np.eye(A.shape[0]))

A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
add_val_to_non_diag(A, 1)
=> array([[1., 3., 4.],
          [5., 5., 7.],
          [8., 9., 9.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is rather hacky than straight one (the one that applies `np.eye`):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
def add_val_to_non_diag(A, v):
    x, y = np.indices(A.shape)
    return A + v*(x!=y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy already has that feature built in.
Use code example below:

```
#To fill the diagonal
np.fill_diagonal(A, 100)
#then to add to the diagonal use the code below
np.fill_diagonal(A, A.diagonal() + 100)
```

Comment: "...but the diagonal elements."

Comment: and *add* - not *assign* - which is what you are doing